# How to retrieve text as typed in Mysql mediumtext field?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a Mysql database with text table, that contains:
`id=int(30) and text=mediumtext;`
I typed as below, for example, and saved in the table, as `id=1`.

Whent i retrieve the field:

> This is a text.
>
> ```
>               This is a new line, with a big space before text.
>
>  here contains more info.
> ```

```
      $id=GetRow("SELECT text from text_table WHERE id=1");
```

I got this:

```
"     This is a text.
           This is a new line,
      that contains more info."
```

Without new lines, paragraphs or tabs.

How i retrieve as typed?

Thx!

Comment: use `nl2br()` over your resultant string from mysql

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($id);`?

Comment: your browser expects HTML, in HTML `<br>` is a line break not "\n" or "\r" which is what is used in plain text

Comment: Yes, browser expects <br> and &nbsp, but is stored as i typed. Is not possible to retrieve that?

Comment: you need to convert the stored "\n" or "\r"  to `<br>` as @MKhalidJunaid suggest nl2br()

Comment: I didn´t use <br>, or &nbsp; when i input.

Comment: yes ... so you convert to them

Comment: echo nl2br($id) solved the new line<br> issue, but not the space (paragraph tab), the &nbsp; issue. THX @MKhalidJunaid.

Comment: Thx for everybody, i found a way. If anyone face this issue this what i did:<pre><?echo nl2br($id)?></pre>